# Why doesn't scrollTop change -webkit-filter: blur()?

Tags: jquery, css, scrolltop, css-filters

Here's a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/brockwhittaker/9Lk4v54h/

Here's my JS:

```
$(window).scroll ->
 scrollValue = ($(window).scrollTop())
 $(".img").css "webkitFilter : blur", scrollValue
```

and CSS:

```
#height {
 height: 200vh;
}
#img {
 -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
}
```

Basically, I'm trying to get the blur radius to change as I scroll down, but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
<div id="height">
<img id="img" src='https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7474/16082786652_6372b547bd_n.jpg' />
</div>
```

Anybody know why it doesn't work?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: The JSFiddle doesn't match up with what you're asking in the question.

Comment: I have no idea what your third line in the JS code snippet is supposed to do.  It doesn't even look valid

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/brockwhittaker/9Lk4v54h/ This is correct now. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're maybe using CoffeeScript but your jsfiddle isn't using it, so I'm just going to use regular JavaScript with jQuery.

Your selector for `img` is wrong.  Use the period `.` to select by class and use pound/hash `#` to select by ID.

Try this (convert to CoffeeScript if you like):

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
  var scrollValue = $(window).scrollTop();
  $("#img").css("webkitFilter", "blur(" + scrollValue + "px)");
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4qrx9h91/)

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thank you. :) 
And oops on the . vs #. Thanks for finding that.